# Does GetLastError() return always meaningful codes when a call has suceeded?

Tags: winapi

Is it guaranteed that all Windows APIs filling GetLastError() on errors also set GetLastError() to ERROR_SUCCESS if there's usually no reason to check GetLastError(), i.e. when the call before has succeeded ?
And are are there some calls that usually return success only with a boolean state and distinguish different success codes later with GetLastError() ?

Comment: The only guaranty is *"If called failed then Last Error will be meaningful"* when the API is documented to do so.

Comment: @sim No, that's not the guarantee. The guarantee is documented for each API call. The call need not have failed for `GetLastError` to return a meaningful value. Likewise, most GDI calls do not set the last error code on failure.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it guaranteed that all Windows APIs filling GetLastError() on errors also set GetLastError() to ERROR_SUCCESS if there's usually no reason to check GetLastError(), i.e. when the call before has succeeded ?

No. In fact, most APIs that report an error code via `GetLastError()` DO NOT reset the error code on success, thus the error code from a previous failure (or even an internal failure) is preserved. Only a handful of APIs do reset the error code on success, when success codes have specific meaning. Those APIs are explicitly documented as doing so.

In general, if an API is not documented as setting the error code on success/failure, do not make any assumptions about the state of the error code on success/failure.

> And are are there some calls that usually return success only with a boolean state and distinguish different success codes later with GetLastError() ?

There are some APIs that do that, yes. For example, `CreateMutex()` returns a non-null handle on success, and then `GetLastError()` returns either 0 if the handle is to a mutex object that was created anew, or returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if the handle is to a pre-existing named mutex object.

But such cases are generally rare.

Comment: Might add that there are plenty of times where a successful call will still alter the error code to something set by a failed internal call, even though the outer call succeeded. If the docs don't say that GetLastError has meaning on success you generally can't trust it to have any value in particular.